# What is "Antipodean English"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, dialects, accent, antipodean-english

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jHfY0dDZxA) where the English gentleman asks the Scottish MP to speak in "Antipodean English". From what I know, 'Antipodes' refers to the southern hemisphere and I am unable to understand why the gentleman would want the other person to speak a dialect from that broad region in particular. Because this seems unlikely, I want to know what the person meant by the term "Antipodean English".

Comment: This is answered by the dictionary entry for "Antipodean"/"Antipodes" (which does not define it as the entire southern hemisphere) or even the tag description here on this site.

Comment: Sorry about that, I did not know about the background of Sir Paul Beresford MP. I do admit that my tone sounds rather peevish in the question. I apologise for it, I did not mean to deride anybody.

Comment: Your tone is fine. But you need to use a dictionary before asking a question like this so that answerers aren't just retreading what's already readily available in dictionaries. It might not have helped you understand the humor but your question would be that much more solid with the right definition (and I think you can still edit to fix that).

Comment: @Laurel - if the definition is added in, is the question not invalidated? The OP is asking what the term means, not the features of the dialect. (Which would be interesting, but irrelevant.)

Comment: @Heartspring The existing answer only spends a single sentence on correcting the mistaken definition so there's not much to invalidate. It also shows that there's (fortunately) a bit more substance to the question than just redefining words. Of course, the most important thing will be for OP to take my advice for future questions.

Answer (score 6):

Here "Antipodean" means "Australia and New Zealand".

[Sir Paul Beresford MP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Beresford) (your English gentleman) was born in New Zealand, and moved to the UK as an adult.

[David Linden MP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Linden_(politician)) (your Scottish MP) was born and grew up in Glasgow, the largest city in Scotland.

The comment was an attempt at a humorous request for Linden to repeat the question in a way Beresford could understand (in a room with historically poor acoustics).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sir Paul Beresford had an unmistakable English accent so I was really confused why he would be talking about Australia or New Zealand.

Comment: Sir Paul Beresford's accent is light, but marked enough for an Australian to be able to spot he is a New Zealander.